# Integration $\int \left(\tan^{2}(x) + \tan^{4}(x)\right)\,dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int \left(\tan^{2}(x) + \tan^{4}(x)\right)\,dx$$

My attempt:

$$\int \left(\left(\sec^{2}(x)-1\right) + \left(\sec^{2}(x)-1\right)^2\right)\,dx= \int\left(\sec^{4}(x) - \sec^2(x)\right)\,dx.$$

I think I made it a little easier since I know $$\int\sec^2(x)\,dx = \tan(x) + C.$$ How would I integrate $\sec^{4} (x)$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int \left[\tan^2x + \tan^4x\right] \ \mathrm dx
&=& \displaystyle \int \tan^2x \left[1+\tan^2x\right] \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int \tan^2x \sec^2x \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int \tan^2x \ \mathrm d(\tan x) \\
&=& \dfrac13 \tan^3x +C
\end{array}$$

Comment: This is my way(+1)

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\int \sec^4 x-\sec^2 x\ dx = \int \sec^2 x(\sec^2 x-1)\ dx= \int \sec^2 x \tan^2 x\ dx
\end{align}
then use u-sub where $u = \tan x$.

Comment: Ahhh, I think i could have done that the very first step. Thx

Comment: @Tinler I think we were looking at $\int \tan^2 x + \tan^4\ dx$ instead.